# How to create async function for onCall firebase functions system

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to upload my cloud functions but I have an error during the upload :

```
  14:63  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
```

The function :

```js
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, ctx) => {
  //my code
}
```

The error is the arrow...

But this error happen just when I deploy my functions on the cloud but with the emulator nothing appear.

Comment: Maybe the cloud supports only ES5 and not ES6 ?

Comment: Are you using eslint? If yes, can you share the config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided is correct, you most likely have eslint added and configured to default's which have very strict settings.
Setting the Env value to es6 or newer should resolve this issue.

```
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018
  }
```